# How can I log an entire HTTP request in WAI/scotty?

Tags: haskell

I currently run the middleware logStdoutDev from Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger, but it only logs the path and the Accept header (possibly other headers too). I want to see the body of the POST and PUT requests as well. This body happens to be json, so just printing it to stdout will do fine.

I have searched for a WAI middleware that logs everything but have not found any. I don't really know enough about WAI internals to write something that extracts POST body and then puts it back in myself, so I was hoping to avoid that learning curve right now.

Comment: I currently just use "body >>= liftIO . putStrLn . show" in each route handler, but this is obviously not DRY. I want to do it one step earlier.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is provided from the `wai-extra` package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware logStdoutDev
  get "/" $ do
    text "example"
```

Example output:

```
Setting phasers to stun... (port 3000) (ctrl-c to quit)
GET /
  Accept: */*
  Status: 200 OK 0.000050947s
```

Answer (score 3):

WAI `Middleware` is just a transformation over `Application`:

```
type Middleware = Application -> Application
```

And `Application` is just a handler:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

All you need to do is define handler that will log whatever you want and delegate "real work" downstream:

```
-- note that this is equivalent to Application -> Application
logAllMiddleware :: Application -> Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
logAllMiddleware app req respond = do
    print . unpack . requestBody req
    app req respond
```

Please keep in mind that I wrote this code without access to ghc. It may not be completely correct.